# Como gerar arquivos de log com data log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Boa tarde a todos,

Estou usando o log4j(log4j-1.2.17.jar) pra gerar o log do sistema, porem agora preciso gerar o log com datae fazer com q ele gere um log a cada dia, preciso que o log seja gerado assim "testeLog-20-05-2016.log" e tb preciso fazer com q quando vire o dia crie um novo log.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,stdout,fileOut

log4j.category.fileOut=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout


log4j.appender.fileOut.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %5p %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileOut =org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileOut.File=d://logTeste.log
log4j.appender.fileOut.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

não faço ideia de como colocar a data no nome do arquivo, alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para resolver o problema precisei do jar "datedFileAppender-1.0.3.jar"

e a configuração ficou a seguinte:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,stdout,fileOut

log4j.category.fileOut=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.fileOut=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileOut.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %5p %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileOut.Directory=d://
log4j.appender.fileOut.Prefix=arqLog-
log4j.appender.fileOut.append=true
log4j.appender.fileOut.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Pela [documentação](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender), você deve usar um `RollingFileAppender` como você fez, usando a propriedade `FilePattern` em conjunto com a File:

```
log4j.appender.fileOut.FilePattern=d://logTeste-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
```